# Proving an inequality $0 \lt x_1 \lt x_2 \leq 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the following problem (context: self-study, not for a math course).

Assume $ 0 \lt x_1 \lt x_2 \leq 1$. Then it follows, that  $\dfrac{1} {x_2} + x_2 < \dfrac{1}{x_1} + x_1.$

I was basically trying the whole day to find a proof, to no avail.
From the assumption it follows that $\dfrac{1} {x_2} < \dfrac{1} {x_1}.$

But on the other hand, we have $x_1 < x_2$, so the result is immediate. And no matter which strategy I was trying to apply, I always ran into basically the same problem. So although it assume that this is a simple and basic problem, I am stuck.

I would be most appreciative for some help.

Comment: If you know calculus you can show easily that the function is decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\frac1{x_1}+x_1-\left(\frac1{x_2}+x_2\right)&=\frac{x_2-x_1+x_1^{\,2}x_2-x_1x_2^{\,2}}{x_1x_2}\\&=\left(\frac1{x_1x_2}-1\right)(x_2-x_1).\end{align}Now, use the fact that $\frac1{x_1x_2}>1$, since $0<x_1,x_2\leqslant1$ and you don't have $x_1=x_2=1$.

Comment: Nice answer. Observe  that the OP assumed that $x_1<x_2$, so the case where $x_1=x_2=1$ is impossible anyway.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Thank you. I knew that $x_1<x_2$ and that's why I wrote “you don't have $x_1=x_2=1$.”

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: You can simplify the algebra a bit by writing $x_2=x_1+\delta$, where $0<\delta<1$.